# Deliberately ambiguous translation of "Songs of the wild dog"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am translating the phrase "Songs of the wild dog" into Latin, and I have the following:

> <s>Canti</s> Cantus Canis Feri

For context, this is the title of a music album I am working on. Aside from accuracy in translation, could this phrase mean anything else? I like double-meanings, so it would be a big bonus to me if the translation of the phrase had additional valid interpretations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The regular noun *cantus* is of the fourth declension, so the genitive would be *cantus*. Because *cantus* can also be nominative or accusative plural, and the other two words are also multisignificant, you'd get many neat possibilities, some farther fetched than others:

**CANTVS CANIS FERI**:

- Song of the wild dog
- Wild songs of a dog
- You sing songs of the wild
- Strike up songs of the dog (*ferio* can mean "strike, punish, sacrifice, offer")
- Beat the dogs of song (alternative accusative plural *-is*)
- O, dog, you must sacrifice songs!
- O, sung dog, you must sacrifice! (participle *cantus* of *cano*, nominativus pro vocativo)

Etc. You figure out how all of this is possible!

Comment: The vocative of *cantus, -a, -um" would be "cante." Word order is why I stayed away from some of those meanings, though it's technically possible in poetry.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer: Well, it is meant to be a nominativus pro vocativo.

Comment: *Cantus, -us* also an enchantment, a charm.

Comment: Out of curiosity I put it into Google Translate since I expect someone might do that. Google gives it as _wild singing dog_, so it's at least directionally accurate.

Comment: @Hugh: The charms of a wild dog, I like it.

Comment: @Adam: Hah, Google Translate is always wrong in unpredictable ways!

Comment: @Cerberus: No kidding. Try asking it to translate goatherd into Latin.

Comment: @Joshua: Hah, unus caprimulgus. That makes exceedingly little sense.

Answer (score 3):

Canti is incorrect. You want *cantus*. Note that the ending of *cantus* is long, as it's a 4th declension noun.

Technically, *feri* could refer to *cantus* (wild songs) or *canis* (wild dog), but because of the word order reading it so as a title isn't really natural.

Comment: Thanks! I made a novice assumption it was second declension.

Comment: @Adam as a heuristic, nouns formed from verbs, describing the action (not the result) and ending in *-us* are very often fourth declension, e.g. *exitus* (from *exire*; exit, outcome, death), *volatus* (from *volare*; flight), *usus* (from *uti*; use) and many more.