# Translate "I will cast my shadow" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

I want to translate *I will cast my shadow* into Latin. This phrase is inspired from a poem by Horace, that has the line:

> Pulvis et Umbra Sumus

My interpretation of this is that we are simply our physical forms and whatever influence (or shadow) we have on the world around us. *I will cast my shadow* is then meant to be a reminder to myself to cast my shadow - to leave my mark, as it were.

My initial thought is something like this:

> <s>Umbra</s> Umbram Iaciam

I'm not sure whether [iacio](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/iacio) is the right verb for throwing or casting something like a shadow, though, or whether it would even make sense in that usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, *umbra* must be in the accusative case, so it has to be **umbram iaciam**.

As to the correctness of the phrase, it is in fact classical: Lewis & Short have meaning I.B.5. of *iacio* as "To project as a shadow" giving the reference “nullam umbram,” Plin. 2, 73, 75, § 183 sq.

Comment: Ahh, beginner error on my part with using nominative instead of accusative. That's a great reference, too. Thank you!

Comment: @Adam On this site, taking inspiration from real literature, thinking critically about the verb choice and not just trying Google Translate (which gives 'Ecce ego inducam super umbra mea') puts you *way* past the beginner level.

Comment: Thanks! One of the first things I found out after joining this site and started my journey to learn Latin, was just [how bad Google translate is](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15648/what-is-the-best-worst-translation-of-latin-from-google-translate).