# How do you say "lost in thought" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

If you google the above question, you will keep running into 'aut in diversorio' but I'm pretty sure this is a machine translation from the book of Kings in the Bible, since that is where the original sentence comes from.
I'm guessing "āmissus/perditus in cogitātiōne" (ablative)

Answer (score 7):

Borrowing an expression from Cicero, I would suggest:

> Cogitatione alio ductus

Which might be translated:

> Led elsewhere (or *carried away*) in thought

This expression comes from Cicero's *De Oratore Ad Quintum Fratrem*:

> Id accidere credo, vel quod ingeni specimen est quoddam transilire
> ante pedes posita et alia longe repetita sumere; vel quod is, qui
> audit, **alio ducitur cogitatione** neque tamen **aberrat**, quae maxima est
> delectatio; (*De Oratore Ad Quintum Fratrem*
> Book III, chap. XXXIX, §160)
>
> (I believe this happens, either because it is some indication of
> intellect to leap over such expressions placed before you and take up
> others from a greater distance; or because the listener is led
> elsewhere in thought, while not straying from the subject, which is
> quite a pleasure.)

**Another option**:

In light of cmw's comment, I'm including another possibility suggested by Cicero's same sentence:

> Cogitatione aberrans

Which might be translated as:

> Wandering away (or *going astray*) in thought

Whether one is *carried away* or *wandering away*, I believe that both ideas are suggestive of being lost in thought. As cmw pointed out, *going astray in thought* may be better suited for conveying the idea of being oblivious to one's surroundings.

Comment: I'm not really sure Cicero's saying people are *lost* in thought. To me this sounds more like a train of thought - jumping from one image to another. And yet the last word is it, I think.

Comment: @cmw - The last word is what? I don't understand what your saying. Isn't being lost in thought following a train a thought to wherever it might lead?

Comment: Sorry, I got lost in thought! I added a post actually, but I think *aberrans* (three words later than your bolded phrase) gets closer to the meaning of "lost." It's not simply following a train of thought - one to the next - which can be done in a simple conversation, but being oblivious to the surroundings in thoughts. And the thought can be singular, you can be lost in a single thought.

Comment: @cmw - OK. Thanks! I included your suggestion in my answer as an alternative option.

Comment: To me both options express rather an _opposite_ of being [lost in thought](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lost%20in%20thought). Cicero speaks about not thinking in a logically consistent way and rather jumping on the subject back and forth, or "losing a thought," like when you suddenly find yourself asking "where was I?" _cogitatione aberrans_, lit. "with one's mind/reasoning facility wandering/going astray" excellently conveys the latter meaning, but it's rather an opposite of being lost _in_ thought, when one goes so deep into a thought as to forget everything else.

Comment: @kkm - I agree that in the present context, Cicero is not using "_alio ducitur cogitatione_" in the sense of being so absorbed as to be oblivious. However, the fact that he thought it necessary to clarify the statement with "_neque tamen aberrat_" suggests that it could be taken as such in some contexts. I also don't understand your last comment, because it seem to me that thinking about something so much as "to forget everything else" would include "not paying attention to one's surroundings", which, according to the link you provided, is what it means to be lost in thought.

Answer (score 6):

For the meaning of being consumed in thought so that to lose touch with surrounding, several options might be suggested.

L&S [suggests](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DO%3Aentry%20group%3D4) ***oblivisci sui*** (literraly: "to forget oneself"), it was suggested by @cmw in a [question about distraction resulting in forgetting](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15919/is-ut-facerem-sed-retro-oblitus-idiomatic-for-i-was-going-to-but-then-i-got). However it seems *oblivisci sui* is wider in meaning than "lost in thought". I believe it is possible to add an ablative of cause/manner to make it clearer, something like "*esse oblitus sui (a) cogitatione/cogitando de hac re*"; Or, even using present participle *esse oblitus sui cogitans de hac re*

With respect to the suggested *perditus/amissus in cogitatione*, it seems to me *perditus* is a bit stronger and has negative connotation for the sense we seek here; id est, something like *perditus (in) cogitatione* is likely to get interpreted as "he got ruin/devastated with that thought" - i.e., the thought had negative effect on him. With respect to *amissus (in) cogitatione*, for time being I could not attest kind of this usage; furthermore in a brief scan, I could not find even one instance of a person as the direct object of *amitto* in the sense we are seeking, let alone *se* (with *perdo* such examples of person direct object can be found that quoted in [L&S entry for *perdo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=perdo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)), hence I would say that *amissus (in) cogitatione* seems quite off, but I might be missing here.

Another option would be to use *captus* (lit. taken) instead of *perditus*, but it has maybe more of the connection of being allured or charmed. L&S lists several examples of this kind of usage like *(bos) herbā captus viridi*. But if the thing taken is rather *animum* we might find there:

> is ut animum eius cura sacrorum et caerimoniarum cepit (Liv.; he, when his care (of .., )'took' his mind).

So we might have: ***animus cogitatione caputus*** or even without *animus* (*cogintatione captus*)

Basically integrating *animus* in the phrase might open some options for us, consider for example this quote from Plinus:

> Volō tibi multa alia scrībere, sed **tōtus animus in hāc ūnā contemplātiōne dēfixus est**  (I want to write to you more, but my all being is attached to this one contemplation).

I think it makes good candidate for one who is focused on the thought.

Answer (score 6):

I'll add another one to the list, interestingly from the same book as Expeditio's answer (Cic. Orat. 3.5.17):

> in eam exhedram venisse in qua Crassus lectulo posito recubuisset, cumque eum **in cogitatione defixum** esse sensisset, statim recessisse.

> ...he came to the hall where Crassus was reclining on a couch set up for him, and when [Cotta] noticed that **he** [Crassus] **was lost in thought**, he immediately left.

The participle *defixum* comes from *defigo*, which means "to fix, fasten; to turn intently" or even "to stupefy." The idea is that if you're lost in thought, you're blanking out the rest of the world and "and not paying attention to one's surroundings." So Crassus here is thinking about something (*in cogitatione*) and at the same time oblivious to what's going on around him (which is why Cotta leaves).

Answer (score 5):

(This isn't an answer, but it's too long for a comment.)

"Aut in diversorio" from 1 Kings 18:27 isn't a machine translation, it's the text of the Vulgate. Here's the full verse:

> Cumque esset iam meridies, illudebat illis Elias, dicens: Clamate voce maiore: deus enim est, et forsitan loquitur, **aut in diversorio est**, aut in itinere, aut certe dormit, ut excitetur.

My quick literal translation:

> And as it was noon already, Elias mocked them, saying: "Call out with a louder voice: for he is a god, and perhaps he is talking [to someone], **or in an inn**, or on a journey, or at any rate asleep, that he may be awoken."

Various translators have rendered *in diversorio* in various ways, with various degrees of plausibility ([KJV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=I+Regum+18%3A27&version=KJV): "or he is pursuing"; [CEB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=I+Regum+18%3A27&version=CEB): "or wandering"; [ISV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=I+Regum+18%3A27&version=ISV): "Maybe he’s relieving himself"). Lewis & Scott say *diversorium* is a variant of [*deversorium*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0060:entry=deversorium) 'inn, lodging-house', and I deferred to them; the [Septuagint](https://www.academic-bible.com/en/online-bibles/septuagint-lxx/read-the-bible-text/bibel/text/lesen/stelle/11/180001/189999/ch/303fcd2a2503f32242a8a9e631516c6d/), at least, seems not to have an exact corresponding part to shed more light on the intended meaning (I'm not in a position to judge any Hebrew).
I suspect the confusion is due to someone who speaks English but not a lot of Latin. The [CEB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=I+Regum+18%3A27&version=CEB) actually seems to translate *loquitur* as 'he is lost in thought', which is definitely not tenable and may have contributed.

At any rate, translating idioms word-for-word is not likely to produce good results.